# BufferedImage's setData() throws exception with TYPE_INT_RGB

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, raster

I am trying to do create a *BufferedImage* from pixel data. Following is my sample code. It works fine for TYPE_BYTE_GRAY but throws *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* for TYPE_INT_RGB

```
BufferedImage originalImage=<received from the caller>;
Raster raster = originalImage.getData();
SampleModel sampleModel = raster.getSampleModel();

WritableRaster writableRaster= Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, new  Point(0,0));
/*
 * Write data to the writableRaster
 */
int imageType;

if(isColordImage)
    imageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
else
    imageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;

BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, imageType);
newImage.setData(writableRaster);
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you set `imageType`, `imageWidth` and `imageHeight`?

Comment: I (do) set these 2 variables before use as `originalImage.getWidth()` and `originalImage.getHeight()`

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Can you post a complete short program that demonstrates the bug?